# Pine script Tradingview renko alerts first box open to second box open

Tags: pine-script

Probably most stupid question ever, but I am getting alerts right now whenever the renko chart changes color/direction. After a the first red or green box I get an alert. Basically this means that you're always in the market. That's not what I want.

What I would like:
1. Open alert after 2nd new red or green box.
2. Close after first new red or green box.

I have no knowledge of pine script and therefore would like to ask if someone can give me guidance.
[Please check for the image here of how it is right now.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pxes5.png)

I would like the open long and short arrows to open 1 box later. So after the 2nd box into the long side = open long. After the 2nd box into the short side = open short.

The code right now is:

```
    //@version=2
    study("Renko Reversal alert", overlay=true) 
    //Buy entry if a bearish renko brick is followed by a bullish brick
    //Sell entry if a bullish brick is followed by a bearish brick
    long = close > open[1] and close[1] < open[2]
    short = close < open[1] and close[1] > open[2]

    //Use these alerts to create server-side alerts (right-click on one of the buy or sell arrows on the chart and choose "add alert")
    alertcondition(long, title='Long opportunity', message='Renko reversal')
    alertcondition(short, title='Short opportunity', message='Renko reversal')

    //Use this to customize the look of the arrows to suit your needs.
    plotshape(long, location=location.belowbar, color=lime, style=shape.arrowup, text="Buy")
    plotshape(short, location=location.abovebar, color=red, style=shape.arrowdown, text="Sell")
```

I would imagine that I need to change something here but I have no idea what I would change it into:
long = close > open[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pxes5.png) and close[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pxes5.png) < open[2]
short = close < open[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pxes5.png) and close[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pxes5.png) > open[2]

Would love to hear if someone can help.

Kind regards,

M.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably read about [History Referencing Operator](https://www.tradingview.com/wiki/Operators#History_Referencing_Operator_.28Square_Brackets_.5B.5D.29).

`long = close > open[1] and close[1] < open[2]` means that, if current close (`close`) is greater than the open price of one bar ago (`open[1]`) AND (`and`) if close price of one bar ago (`close[1]`) is lower than open price of two bars ago (`open[2]`).

So, what you want to do is shift all those values by one bar by increasing the history index and then add a condition for the current bar.

```
long = close[1] > open[2] and close[2] < open[3] and close > open
short = close[1] < open[2] and close[2] > open[3] and close < open
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Baris, thank you so much. That works like a charm. The only problem I have with that though is that the position doesn't close after the first new red or green brick. Please see image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kBKCE.png

So a new position should be opened after 2 new bricks of a new color have formed, but the close should be after the 1st new brick of a new color. I hope you get the idea from the image. Any idea how I can solve that?

Comment: Then the `short` should be same as in your question. `short = close < open[1] and close[1] > open[2]`. Is this what you want?

Comment: Hi Baris, sorry for the late response. That really solved everything. Got my indicator running now and it's working perfectly. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: No problem. I’m glad I was able to help.

Comment: Hi Baris, one further question with which I hope you can help. Obviously the choppiness screws you over sometimes. I was hoping to cut this out by adding this rule: ONLY open long when price closes ABOVE ema21 and ema50 AND ema21 > ema50. Vice versa for short positions obviously. How would I translate that into pinescript code? Hope you can help.

Answer (score 0):

how give buy signal when first 3 green box is formed

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).